# Lubuntu: Dragging image from web browser (Falcon) is not effective

Tags: lubuntu, drag-and-drop, context-menu, webbrowser-app

When I want to move an image from an internet browser (for example from Google images), it works worse than in the Windows operating system. Specifically, I am concerned about these two things:

1. I have a web browser open in full screen. in Windows, it was enough to grab the image with the mouse and drag it to the desktop display button. Then the desktop appeared and I just dropped the image and it was done.
2. when I want to place (drop) an image on the desktop, I get a context menu with the options "copy, move, create symlink". these options are completely useless to me and only delay me. How do I prevent this offer (menu) from appearing?

Thank you for your answer.

My system release datails are:

- Distributor ID: Ubuntu;
- Description: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS;
- Codename: jammy

(output of lsb_release -a commant)

Comment: LXQt & Lubuntu aim at being *light*, which means providing basic features as the more *features* you add the *heavier* the system gets.  The browser you mention `falcon` also aims at being *light* (ie. minimal features so you get a minimal memory footprint).. yet you're now wanting the features/choices of a *heavy* system; why not use one?

Comment: Heavy Features? in fact, I consider it as the basis for effective work. after all, it can't be difficult to program this... moreover, functions of this type would consume practically no resources (power). Maybe the performance would even be better if the context menu was removed... but I understand that's just how it's set up in this system. Therefore, I am asking for advice: which operating system can be used for efficient work, similar to Windows? On Ubuntu? Thank you.